# Delays between servo movements in pyfirmata don't work

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, servo, firmata

I'm writing a program in python where moving servos at specific times is a crucial part of the project. To achive this, I am using the pyfirmata library.

I've tried two methods of delays, but none of them seem to work. 
When I run the code, the servo turns the first time, but after the delay, it doesn't turn and the program just stops, instead of moving the servo to 0 degrees and *then* stopping.

This is the one with the board.pass_time() built in to the pyfirmata library:

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
import time
board = Arduino('COM3')
servo = board.get_pin('d:9:s')

servo.write(180)        #This works and turns the servo
time.sleep(1)
servo.write(0)          #This time the servo does not turn, then the program ends
```

And here's the one with time.sleep():

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
board = Arduino('COM3')
servo = board.get_pin('d:9:s')

servo.write(180)        #This works and turns the servo
board.pass_time(1)
servo.write(0)          #This time the servo does not turn, then the program ends
```

I would highly appreciate if someone could help.

Thank you,
David

Comment: You seem to assume that the program implicitly loops. It doesn't. You'll need to create an outer loop to keep calling those lines of code. Otherwise it will go like any other program; running top-to-bottom then ending when it reaches the last command

Comment: I don't use the library but `servo.write()` to me would specify the number of degrees from its _current_ position. So, to go backwards to the origin, maybe `servo.write(-180)` or to reset whichever way, another rotation of 180 degrees `servo.write(180)`.

Comment: Dear @roganjosh ! Thank you for answering! I know it doesn't repeat. What it's supposed to do is go to position 180, wait 1 second, then go to position 0, then the program will stop, but what it actually does is go to position 180, wait 1 second then it ends without going back to position 0

Comment: Also I checked and the `servo.write()` does specify exactly to what angle it should turn to, but thank you very much for answering, David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!
There might be a better answer, but if I write `board.get_pin('d:9:s')` as `board.get_pin('d:9:')`, like this, I need to control it with a value from 0 to 5 instead of 0 to 360, but the delays work

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but you need to make the delay again to turn it back to 0 degree. So your code should look something like this.

```
servo.write(180)
time.sleep(2)
servo.write(0)
time.sleep(2)
```

You need to give the delay everytime you make changes to the servo motor in order to make those changes